# Where should I define API endpoints in .net core web app?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

If I had a github API - https://api.github.com/users/:username/repos, where should this URL be ideally stored?

Should it be in appsettings.json or should it be defined in the code itself since it requires a username input.

Comment: Store `https://api.github.com` in configuration and use string interpolation to add `/users/:username/repos` at runtime.

Comment: If the API was changed by github in the future that would require that I make changes in all the codes that use it right ?

Comment: Yes, you would have to update your code, so keep that in mind.